# How can I see what gradle task Android Studio is using to install an apk?

Tags: android, android-studio

When I run a configuration, I can the gradle commands android studio is running to build the apk in the build tab (`assembleDebug`). But it is not showing me what command is run after that to actually install the apk on a device. Is there a way I can see this?

Comment: FWIW, `installDebug` is probably what it uses for installing a `debug` build. This depends on `assembleDebug`, so it will build and install the app.

Comment: @CommonsWare Then how would Android Studio specify which device it wants to install the apk to if multiple are present?

Comment: That's an interesting point -- I had not taken that into account. However, in that case, they may not be running a Gradle task to do the install, but rather are doing the equivalent of `adb install` directly.

Comment: @CommonsWare I think if they were doing that it would show in the Run tool window. I don't see any adb commands there except the `am start` command which gets run after installation.